# Benchmarking the time / latency of files

Tags: javascript, benchmarking

I am interested in benchmarking the time / latency of files. Here's a senario, I'd like to take the three files `http://something.com/script1.js`, `http://something.com/script2.js`, and `http://something.com/script3.js`,  and I want to compare the time that these files take to load in a web browser.

I am looking for some kind of tool or chrome extension that will allow me to do this.

(I realize this is not a programming question per-say but I'm desperate)

THIS doesn't need to be javascript specific, could be anything pages, images, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are just looking for load time and not execution just include them all in a blank page, open the page, open chrome dev tool, select the 'network' tab, refresh the page, the network tab will show the three files loading and how long each bit of the request took. If you want execution I think there are a few webpages out there that can test that

Comment: This is how i've been doing it and I would like something that gives me the times cached and uncached. I've been using Charles for the mac but Its not exactly the right fit too. Perhaps a terminal application that uses CURL or whatever? Thanks for your suggestion.